# How to avoid restarting the rectangle when drawing a new one?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm trying to draw multiple rectangles in this program, but whenever I draw a new rectangle, the old rectangle disappears, how can I draw a new rectangle without losing the old rectangle? This is my program:

```
struct Position
{
    Position() : x(0), y(0) {}
    float x, y;
};
Position start, finish;

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        start.x = finish.x = x;
        start.y = finish.y = y;
    }
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        finish.x = x;
        finish.y = y;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, finish.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x, finish.y);
    glEnd();
    
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: Keep a data structure of start and end positions (maybe `vector<pair<Position>>`) that gets added to when you click, then iterate through this list with the drawing code `glBegin(GL_QUADS)` etc...

Comment: I recommend you accept @lisyarus answer as his answer was the first (even if I have done some a little extra work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that simply removing `glClear` would lead to *all* rectangles you ever drawn persisting on the screen - you won't be able to e.g. delete just one of them. It may also lead to the initial contents of the window contain some garbage pixels (though this can be fixed by doing `glClear` just at the start of your program).

A typical solution would be, as jackw11111 suggested, to store all your rectangle coordinates in some data structure (`std::vector` being a perfect choice if you're on C++), and in your `display` function you'd first do the `glClear`, and then iterate over all rectangles and draw them one by one. Something like

```
struct Rectangle
{
    Position start, finish;
};
std::vector<Rectangle> rectangles;

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (Rectangle const & r : rectangles)
    {
        glVertex2f(r.start.x, r.start.y);
        glVertex2f(r.finish.x, r.start.y);
        glVertex2f(r.finish.x, r.finish.y);
        glVertex2f(r.start.x, r.finish.y);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

By the way, you almost definitely don't need `glFlush`.

Answer (score 1):

Cerate a type to store a rectangle:

```cpp
struct Rect
{
    Rect(const Position& s, const Position& f) 
        : start(s), finish(f) {}
    Position start;
    Position finish;
};
```

Use a container of type `std::vector<Rect>` to store the rectangles

```cpp
#include <vector>
```

```cpp
std::vector<Rect> rects;
```

When a rectangle is finished add it to the container:

```cpp
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        start.x = finish.x = x;
        start.y = finish.y = y;
    }
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        finish.x = x;
        finish.y = y;
        rects.emplace_back(start, finish);
        start = finish;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Draw all the rectangles in a loop:

```cpp
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for (auto& rect : rects)
    {
        glVertex2f(rect.start.x, rect.start.y);
        glVertex2f(rect.finish.x, rect.start.y);
        glVertex2f(rect.finish.x, rect.finish.y);
        glVertex2f(rect.start.x, rect.finish.y);
    }
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, finish.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x, finish.y);
    glEnd();
    
    glFlush();
}
```

---

Additionally you can get a nice drawing effect by implementing the [`glutMotionFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node51.html) callback:

```cpp
void motion(int x, int y)
{
    finish.x = x;
    finish.y = y;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // [...]

    glutMotionFunc(motion);

    // [...]
}
```

[image]

---

Implementation for `GL_LINE_LOOP` [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive):

```cpp
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (auto& rect : rects)
    {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex2f(rect.start.x, rect.start.y);
        glVertex2f(rect.finish.x, rect.start.y);
        glVertex2f(rect.finish.x, rect.finish.y);
        glVertex2f(rect.start.x, rect.finish.y);
        glEnd();
    }

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, finish.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x, finish.y);
    glEnd();
    
    glFlush();
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works for `GL_QUADS` but if I change it to `GL_LINE_LOOP` to draw the unfilled rectangle, the rectangles keeps connecting to another rectangles, I don't know why.

Comment: @user Yes of course, because in this case you have to move `glBegin`/`glEnd` in the loop. However this is a new question. Anyway I've extended the answer (see the last paragraph)